# archive files from sharepoint library folder(s) to another folder(s) in a different library programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I need your help. I have a SharePoint library called Library1 and it has some folders with files in them. I would like to move these files from library1 to library2 based on an expiry date.

```
Library1
   Folder1
       file1
       file2
       File3

Library2
```

Can anyone tell me how can I move files from one library to another in their respective folders and remove them from the original library?